# Recursion mess while checking object properties

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, lodash, traversal

I have an object which could be nested as deep as possible. I'm trying to determine if object's property `ready` has at least one false value. If so the `checkForFalse` function should return false. I got confused while using recursion to solve this problem. What recursion call should return to make this code work? Or I'm completely wrong and missing something?

```js
var obj = {

    "currentServiceContractId": {
        "ready": true,
        "customerPersonId": {
            "ready": false
        }
    },

    "siteId": {
        "ready": true
    },

    "districtId": {},

    "localityId": {
        "ready": true
    },

    "streetId": {
        "ready": true
    }
};


function checkForFalse(mainObj) {

    let ans = _.find(mainObj || obj, (val) => {

        if (_.keys(val).length > 1) {

            let readyObj = _.pick(val, 'ready');

            return checkForFalse(readyObj);

        } else {
            return _.get(val, 'ready') === false;
        }

    });

    return _.isEmpty(ans);

}

console.log(checkForFalse(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem? What's the output vs what you expect?

Comment: I expect to have console.log to output `false` if any of object property named `ready` has `false` value. Now I'm always getting `false` console logged

Comment: Just an observation. You have a function named `checkForFalse` that you want to return `false` if there is a false.  To me that's a very misleading function name,. Without knowing what the function did, I would expect by it's name that `checkForFalse` would return `true` if a found a `false`.

Comment: @Keith is right. Something like `checkForAllReady` would better reflect the idea behind the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses `_.every()` recursively to search for `ready: false`. The `_.every()` method will return immediately when the callback returns `false`:

```js
function checkForAllReady(mainObj) {
  return _.every(mainObj, (value, key) => {
    if(key === 'ready' && value === false) {
      return false;
    }
    
    if(_.isObject(value)) {
      return checkForAllReady(value);
    }
    
    return true;
  });
}

const obj = {"currentServiceContractId":{"ready":true,"customerPersonId":{"ready":true}},"siteId":{"ready":true},"districtId":{},"localityId":{"ready":true},"streetId":{"ready":true}};

console.log(checkForAllReady(obj));

const objWithFalse = _.merge({}, obj, { "streetId":{"ready":false} })
console.log(checkForAllReady(objWithFalse));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```